# Terraform File Layout in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I want to move my infrastructure to GCP using Terraform but I wonder about the proper way to organize my Terraform files. I will have many GCP projects one for each business application (they have little to no relation to each other), inside every project resides both the preprod and the prod environments. My first idea which is based on a book online is as follow:

- I create two git repos one for the modules and the other for my infrastructure. I seperated them to version my modules.
- In my infrastructure git repo I create a folder for each GCP project with a state file per folder for isolation.

am I thinking right or is there any better approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it's a multi repo approach. You have also the monorepo option. Different pros and cons, not especially better

Answer (score 1):

There are advantages and disadvantages and I can share some best practices. You can check and modify based on your requirements and moreover there is little support from Google for Terraform but not completely.

- Organize all your outputs in outputs.tf file and document them in README.md file
- Include helper scripts in a separate directory as static files in the Terraform dosent execute and they need to be loaded in the compute engine instances and they need to be organised into files.
- Seperate lengthy docs from their HCL and use file extension for the files which are used to read by Terraform.
- Publish modules to the proper registry.
- For all the modules you need to include the owner file.
- Put  resources forr each application and project in their own Terraform directories and try to nest all the Terraform code under one directory and split applications into environment-specific sub-directories and use directories based on environments.
- Sensitive information may end up in the state file it's better to use Secret Manager.
- Don't modify Terrafrom state manually it will lead to infrastructure problems.

Answer (score 1):

I work with terraform as follows:

I create a repo for each module and document them (in my case, I did this with terradoc < https://terraform-docs.io/ > in a pipeline for this purpose).

For the product, I use two approaches.

- One of them I allow the dev (when knowledgeable) to interact with the .tf files, in this case there is a main.tf, variable.tf, provider.tf and a varfile for each environment.
- In the other, I create a repository just to keep the infrastructure code, this way, projects where the devs don't have enough knowledge or interest to interact with terraform, don't need to have contact with it.

At all times, the state is always in a versioned bucket, whether AWS or GCP, this guarantees resilience and you won't have headaches in the future when it comes to the state of your infrastructure.